# How to write my own by extension function

Tags: android, kotlin, extension-function

I have a default function like this:

```
fun <T> makeDefault(): Animal<T> = Animal<Nothing>(
    name = "",
    size = 0,
    age = 0
)
```

I saw that there is the `by` operator, which can be used for view models like this:

```
val model: MyViewModel by viewModels()
```

**Question:** How I can create a function that behaves like that for my `makeDefault()`?

What I want to do:

```
val animal: Animal<Dog> by makeDefault()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own *Delegate*, not *extension*:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

class DefaultDelegate<T> {
    private var created: Animal<T> = Animal<Nothing>(
            name = "",
            size = 0,
            age = 0
        )

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Animal<T> {
        return created
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: Animal<T>) {
        created = value
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
val animal: Animal<Dog> by DefaultDelegate()
```

For more information, see [Delegated properties doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html)

Comment: It should be noted that since all this is doing is returning a constant instance, a delegate is just introducing extra overhead for no benefit.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer and thank you @Tenfour04 for the useful comment